# Не сохраняется правило iptables

Tags: ubuntu, https, iptables

Новые правила Iptables слетают при перезагрузке сервера...

```
Открываю https 443 порт. 
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
Сохраняю
sudo service iptables-persistent save
Перезагружаю 
sudo reboot
```

Правило слетает, порт снова закрыт. 
Что я делаю не так, как в моём случае правильно сохранить?
Os ubuntu

UPD:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Nov  9 02:06:35 2015
*filter
:INPUT DROP [29:1737]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:ALLOWED_TCP - [0:0]
:BAD_TCP_PACKETS - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -m set --match-set fail2ban-ssh-ddos src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -m set --match-set fail2ban-ssh src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -j BAD_TCP_PACKETS
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80 -j ALLOWED_TCP
-A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 22,80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 3306 -j ALLOWED_TCP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p tcp -j BAD_TCP_PACKETS
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -j BAD_TCP_PACKETS
-A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ALLOWED_TCP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j ACCEPT
-A ALLOWED_TCP -p tcp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ALLOWED_TCP -p tcp -j DROP
-A BAD_TCP_PACKETS -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK SYN,ACK -m state --state NEW -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A BAD_TCP_PACKETS -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j DROP
-A BAD_TCP_PACKETS -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Nov  9 02:06:35 2015
```

Comment: пожалуйста, приложите к вопросу вывод команды: `$ cat /etc/iptables/rules.v4`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, приложил

Comment: Механизм работы iptables таков, что все установленные правила не сохраняются при перезагрузке. Решение: вынесите ваши правила в отдельный скрипт и добавьте его а автозапуск. Iptables имеет для этого специальные возможности, подробности [тут](https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/iptables/#SAVEANDRESTORE)

Comment: @ВладимирМарков, я правильно понимаю, что все перечисленные в `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` правила (и только они) благополучно добавляются в таблицы *netfilter-а* после загрузки? посмотреть текущее содержимое таблиц можно командой `sudo iptables-save`.

Comment: `iptables-persistent` не предназначен для сохранения настроек правил `iptables`, а лишь для загрузки их при старте системы. Для сохранения используйте другую команду, `iptables-save` как рекомендуют в комментариях и ответе. На просторах интернета можно найти ещё и такой вариант: `dpkg-reconfigure iptables-persistent`. Должен подойти для линухов на основе дебияна

Comment: @banme, насколько я вижу, вы не правы по поводу «не предназначен». скрипт `/etc/init.d/iptables-persistent`, входящий в пакет `iptables-persistent`, принимает в качестве аргумента (в том числе) и слово *save*, а если заглянуть внутрь скрипта, то видно, что для сохранения как раз и используется программа `/sbin/iptables-save` (точнее, *symlink* на `/sbin/xtables-multi`).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Полный скрипт в комментарий не влезет, приведу лишь одну строку: `echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|force-stop|restart|force-reload|status}" >&2`

Comment: @banme, вероятно, это не скрипт из пакета для дистрибутива ubuntu. я просмотрел [пакеты](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=iptables-persistent&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) (там, собственно, три версии). все они содержат параметр `save`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin всели версии убунты пересмотрели? Вопрошающий вроде нигде не упоминает какая у него:)

Comment: @banme, я просмотрел все пакеты по приведённой ссылке. как я уже написал, там всего три версии: 0.5.3, 0.5.7 и 1.0.3 (в которой скрипт называется уже по-другому, но параметр — присутствует).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ну значит у него убунта не той версии (11 или ещё старее) или какая-то из этих версий работает неправильно. А service кстати точно передаёт параметр save дальше. Может фильтрует всё, что не связано с запуском и остановкой сервиса?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Ещё вариант. На 99,9% верный. Вообще не установлен это пакет `iptables-persistent`:)

Answer (score 1):

Для начала сохраняем правила например сюда:

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules
```

Далее, для восстановления правил создадим скрипт (в каталоге `if-pre-up.d` нельзя использовать точки в названии файлов):

```
/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptablesload
```

С таким содержимым:

```
#!/bin/sh
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
exit 0
```

Ну и не забываем про права:

```
chmod +x /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptablesload
```

Нужно заметить что `NetworkManager` конфликтует с `iptables`.
Отключить его можно так:

```
sudo stop network-manager
```

Что-бы не запустился во время загрузки:

```
echo "manual" | sudo tee /etc/init/network-manager.override
```